# styling axis labels in a metricsgraphics chart

Tags: javascript, css, metricsgraphicsjs

I've created a metricsgraphics chart and attempted to increase the font size of the axis labels: http://jsfiddle.net/hk63jfg3/1/

My js:

```
 MG.data_graphic({
    title: "sightings",
    data: [{
        'date': new Date('2014-10-28'),
        'value': 7
    }, {
        'date': new Date('2014-11-01'),
        'value': 12
    }, {
        'date': new Date('2014-11-02'),
        'value': 18
    }],
    width: 400,
    height: 250,
    target: '#sightings',
    x_accessor: 'date',
    y_accessor: 'value',
});
```

and CSS:

```
.mg-x-axis text, .mg-y-axis text, .mg-histogram .axis text {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

The year and month are colliding, is there a way to fix this via CSS or better chart options?

Answer (score 0):

### Using CSS

- You can position the year-marker by using `transform: translate(x,y)`.
- You can style the text with all properties listed [in the W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#SVGStylingProperties),
  e.g. making it bold or changing the color:

  ```
  text {
      font-weight: bold;
      fill: rebeccapurple;
      font-size: 30px;
  }
  ```
- If the year-marker collides with a month-marker seperate them with `translate(0,10px)` and make the year-marker visible with:

  ```
  svg {
      overflow: visible !important;
  }
  ```

```js
$(function () {
    MG.data_graphic({
        title: "sightings",
        data: [{
            'date': new Date('2014-10-28'),
            'value': 7
        }, {
            'date': new Date('2014-11-01'),
            'value': 12
        }, {
            'date': new Date('2014-11-02'),
            'value': 18
        }],
        width: 400,
        height: 250,
        target: '#sightings',
        x_accessor: 'date',
        y_accessor: 'value',
    });
});
$(".mg-year-marker text").attr("fill", "red");
```

```css
.mg-x-axis text, .mg-y-axis text, .mg-histogram .axis text {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}



svg {
    overflow: visible !important;
    height: 300px;
}

g.mg-year-marker {
     transform: translate(100px, 15px);
}

g.mg-year-marker text {
    font-size: 2rem;
    fill: rebeccapurple;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://metricsgraphicsjs.org/css/metricsgraphics.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://metricsgraphicsjs.org/js/metricsgraphics.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id='sightings'></div>
</body>
```

### Using Javascript

- You can always get the inner DOM of an SVG element with `document.getElementById("my-svg-id").contentDocument`and manipulate the text-elements by setting their attributes.
  E.g. making a marker red by using `setAttribute("fill","red");`) within the svg-dom.
- **But in your case the svg is in an iframe, which you can't access because of the same-origin-policy**.